# First order ode integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi could anyone help me to solve this first order differential equation.

$$2y e^{y^2}y'=2x+3 \sqrt x$$

I tried using the integrating factor method but i do not know how to find the integreating factor for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

This first order differential equation is separable since the lhs is just the derivative of $e^{y^2}$ with respect to $y$.

I am sure that you can take from here.